# OpenBUGS: get a sample from a random variable

Tags: statistics, bayesian

I'm working in OpenBugs, and I've defined the next model: $Y\sim {\rm Exp}(\theta)$ so I'm asked to assign different initial distributions to $\theta$: Normal, Gamma and log-normal, to this point everything is fine, the model is initiliazed but I want to get a sample $(Y_{(n)})$ and get an histogram. How can I do this??

Comment: I don't know anything about OpenBugs, but in something like Matlab, you would let $U_1$ be $U(0,1)$, choose your parameter $\theta=Q_\theta(U_1)$ where $Q_\theta$ is the quantile function of the parameter distribution. Then let $U_2$ be $U(0,1)$ and then your sample is $Q_X(U;\theta)$ where $Q_X(\cdot;\theta)$ is the quantile function of the exponential distribution.

Comment: For example: u1=rand(100,1);u2=rand(100,1);theta=u1;x=-log(u2)./theta Then you have 100 samples from a $\text{Exp}(\theta)$ distribution where $\theta$ is itself distributed as $U(0,1)$ (and conditionally independent of the exponential).